# Removing duplicates from list based on custom definition of duplicate

Tags: python, list, duplicates, nested-lists

I'm dealing with a nested list that looks something like this.

```
mylist =[
    ["First", "Second", "Third"], 
    ["First", "Second", "Third"], 
    ...
]
```

The goal is to remove duplicate elements of mylist based on the following definition: An element is equal to another element if `element1[0] == element2[0]` and `element1[1] == element2[1]`. Basically, only the first two elements count, ignore the rest.

This doesn't seem terribly hard but I'm probably over complicating it and having trouble with it. I think I am close to a solution, which I'll post if it gets done and nobody has answered.

**My main problems:**

I really wish I could turn the list to a set like in more conventional cases--is there any way to give set a custom definition of equivalence? A lot of built-in methods don't work because of that and rewriting them is a bit painful as the indexing always gets screwed up somewhere.

Comment: If you have the list `[[1,2,4],[1,2,3]]`, do you care which of the the two survives the cull?

Comment: I should clarify that: nope, either one surviving is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a class that stores the data and override `__eq__`:

```
class MyListThingy(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.data[0]==other.data[0] and self.data[1]==other.data[1]
```

Of course, this won't do any good for sets, which use hashing. for that you have to override `__hash__`:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.data[0],self.data[1]))
```

Comment: This sounds good. However, giving set() a list of MyListThingy objects raises an unhashable instance error (with the __hash function in the class).

Comment: Oops, I meant `__hash__`.

Comment: Ah, works perfectly now, I thought you wanted to write hash as a private method (I think __ is used to denote that?). This is very nice solution that I'll keep in mind, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a tuple of first and second items from inner list to be used as a key in a dictionary. Then add all inner lists into the dictionary which will lead to removal of duplicates.

```
d = dict()
l =[["First", "Second", "Third"], ["First", "Second", "Fourth"]]
for item in l:
      d[(item[0], item[1])]=item
```

Output: ( d.values() )

```
[['First', 'Second', 'Fourth']]
```